# What's best WordNet function for similarity between words?

Tags: python, nltk, analysis, wordnet

I aim to find the similarities between words for about ~10,000 words. I'm using the "word.path_similarity(otherword)" method of the wordnet library but the results I'm getting for the path_similarity are in the range 0-0.1 as opposed to being distributed over 0-1. How is it possible that similarities between 10,000 random words all end up in that narrow range?

Is there a better way to use WordNet for finding similarity between two words?

Answer (score 3):

For context, [here's how this is calculated](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/7ba46b9d52ed0c03bf806193f38d8c0e9bd8a9b4/nltk/corpus/reader/wordnet.py#l728):

1. Claculate the length of the shortest path between the two synsets/words (inclusive).
2. Return the score as 1/pathlen

Therefore a score <.2 is indicative of a pathlength > 5 steps. Inclusive of the two input synsets, that means there are at least 4 synsets between them.

With that said: you're complaint seems to be "according to this metric, two words chosen at random are pretty consistently unrelated! What's going on?" Well, your similarity metric is telling you that random words are generally not closely related. This shouldn't be that surprising. Why are you calculating similarities between random words to begin with?

Comment: I worded my question wrong, sorry. I'm aiming to find similarities between the titles of a set of projects. It was just strange for me to see that more than 80% of the title names resulted in a similarity of 0.05-0.2. I had expected a wider distribution given prior knowledge of what the projects do, and hence expected similar projects to have similarly named titles. But seeing that the words in the titles were all 'random' as per this metric, I'm confused if WordNet's path_similarity is the function I'm looking for to detect how similar two words are semantically.